# MySQL - Export data and then Import again when Triggers Exist

Tags: mysql

I can easily use MySQL Workbench to export data.  And it is easy to export that data with the triggers in the database.
However, when I then go to IMPORT the data to a new schema - what I find is that the tables get created, with triggers, and when the data is then inserted during the restore - the triggers fire - which is not what I want.

What I need is a way to pull the data, import it into another database on another machine, and then create the triggers after all the data has been inserted.

What tools do I use to make this happen?  Surely there are tools that are much more automated than having to export data without triggers.  Export structure with triggers.  And manually playing around to get everything setup.

Comment: Perhaps a different approach where the triggers write to a log table which you then periodically export.

Comment: So far - the best solution is mysqldump without triggers.  And then mysqldump with structure and no data.  Then edit that to remove everything but the trigger create statements.  Manual and labor intensive. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1. Import it to a new table
2. Add triggers on the new table
3. Use `RENAME TABLE new TO orig, orig TO oldcopy`
4. when satisfied `DROP TABLE oldcopy`